Hadoop data getting corrupted at every restart of docker hadoop container
We have docker hadoop setup in our evnironment(One master + three worker nodes) each of them running in a seperate container in single physical server, Hadoop file system inside docker is mapped to NFS share in physical server using docker volumes
Below is the configuration on how we mapped it.
volumes:
  - "/opt/hadoop/dfs:/opt/hadoop/dfs"

We have created few files in hadoop file system inside the docker container and we are able to access it with out any issue, everything works fine untill the restart of container, If container gets restarted all the data inside the file system is getting corrupted and below error we are getting from namenode UI:

There are 272 missing blocks. The following files may be corrupted:

Is this expected behavior?? or am I missing anything?? can anyone please help.
I have gone through few articles but nothing is replicating my issue.

It's expected without shutting down the namenode or datanode completely, yes. Just stopping your computer or Docker doesn't wait for that to happen
